# Function affects exactly half of intended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

So I'm running this Javascript w/jQuery function that reformats the `innerHTML` of all h1 elements with the class "`unformatprice`". The class is removed at the end of the reformatting so that it doesn't get re-reformatted again, when the function runs again.
here are the elements:

```
<h1 class="price unformatprice" id="price-13059062">CAD 25.20</h1>
<h1 class="price unformatprice" id="price-13059163">CAD 25.20</h1>
```

and the function:

```
function currencyreformat(){
    var h2s = document.getElementsByClassName("unformatprice");
    for(var h = 0; h < h2s.length; h++ ) {
        var d = h2s[h].innerHTML; 
        var d1 = d.slice(0,4);
        var d2 = d.replace(d1,"<span style='font-size:12px;'>CAD</span><strong>$"); 
        var d3 = d2.slice(0,-3); 
        var d4 = d2.replace(d3,"");
        h2s[h].innerHTML = d3+"<span style='font-size:15px;'>" + d4 + "</span></strong>";
        jQuery("#" + h2s[h].id).removeClass("unformatprice");
    }
}
```

a formatted element should look  like:

```
<h1 class="price" id="price-13059062">
  <span style="font-size:12px;">CAD</span>
  <strong>
    $25
    <span style="font-size:15px;">.20</span>
  </strong>
</h1>
```

But when I run the function only HALF of the elements actually undergo the change, the other hald undergoes no change, even retains the "unformatprice" class.
**HOWEVER**
When I remove the line that removes the "unformatprice" class:

```
jQuery("#" + h2s[h].id).removeClass("unformatprice");
```

ALL elements get formatted!
I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, lease see this fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/CqYCy/3/

Comment: Should `h+1` be `h++`?

Comment: yes, it was initially that, but I changed it just to check. I'll change it back. But, it makes no difference.

Comment: the reason could be that since you are removing the class which you used to search the element the list h2s is getting modified, so your index going wrong

Comment: Iterate in reverse, and it'll work. And FYI, `jQuery("#" + h2s[h].id)` isn't the way to do this. There's no reason to perform DOM selection for an element you already have. `jQuery(h2s[h])`

Comment: ...and are you aware that `.getElementsByClassName()` isn't supported in IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is a "*live*" collection.

This means, as you `.removeClass()`, elements will be removed from `h2s`. So, incrementing `h` seems to jump 2 elements -- 1 for the increment itself and 1 because the removal caused a shift in indexes from `h` to `length - 1`.

One option is to convert the collection to a non-*live* `Array`:

```
var h2s = document.getElementsByClassName("unformatprice");
h2s = Array.prototype.slice.call(h2s, 0);
```

You can also loop from the end of the collection and decrement so `h` stays less than of the indexes being affected by the removals:

```
for (var h = h2s.length - 1; h >= 0; h--) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: addding `h2s = Array.prototype.slice.call(h2s, 0);` worked perfect! Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment the reason could be that since you are removing the class which you used to search the element the list h2s is getting modified, so your index going wrong

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    currencyreformat();//run function
});
function currencyreformat(){
    var h2s = document.getElementsByClassName("unformatprice");//getting unformatted elements
    while(h2s.length > 0){
        var d = h2s[0].innerHTML; 
        var d1 = d.slice(0,4);//getting just the "CAD " part
        var d2 = d.replace(d1,"<span style='font-size:12px;'>CAD</span><strong>$"); //Replacing "CAD " with "<span style='font-size:12px;'>CAD</span><strong>$"
        var d3 = d2.slice(0,-3); //get everything but the last three characters (the cent values)-".20"
        var d4 = d2.replace(d3,"");//removing everything but "0.20"
        h2s[0].innerHTML = d3+"<span style='font-size:15px;'>" + d4 + "</span></strong>";//adding the "CAD$25" to ".20" with the formatting applied.
        jQuery("#" + h2s[0].id).removeClass("unformatprice");//removing the unformatted
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SjhtD/)

But since you are using jQuery the fix should be, it has a minor bug with a space between $ and the number. trying to fix it

```
function currencyreformat(){
    $('.unformatprice').html(function(i, html){
        return html.replace(/^(.{3})\s(.*?)(.{3})$/, '<span style="font-size:12px;">$1</span><strong>$ $2<span style="font-size:15px;">$3</span></strong>')
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SjhtD/2/)

Comment: I didn't try this answer because Jonathan's answer worked for me, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, it's generally a lot more painless to use the "jQuery" way of getting stuff done.

```
function currencyreformat(){
    $(".unformatprice").each(function(){
        var d = $(this).html(); 
        var d1 = d.slice(0,4);
        var d2 = d.replace(d1,"<span style='font-size:12px;'>CAD</span><strong>$"); 
        var d3 = d2.slice(0,-3); 
        var d4 = d2.replace(d3,"");
        $(this).html(d3+"<span style='font-size:15px;'>" + d4 + "</span></strong>");
        $(this).removeClass("unformatprice");
    }
}
```